# MySQL - Using Set Difference with Operand should contain 1 Column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following MYSQL Query Working:

```
SELECT 
    a.author_name, COUNT(*)
FROM
    publication p,
    authored a
WHERE
    a.pubkey = p.pubkey
        AND p.pubkey LIKE '%/asd/%'
GROUP BY a.author_name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1;
```

The above query is to display the name of the author who has publish at least one book in the one book containing the word "asd".

My idea is this to do the set difference. I am trying to find the author who has not published a book containing the word "asd" by using the following sql statement:

```
SELECT 
    a.author_name
FROM
    author a,publication p
WHERE
   a.pubkey = p.pubkey AND a.author_name NOT IN (SELECT 
            a1.author_name, COUNT(*)
        FROM
            publication p1,
            author a1
        WHERE
            a1.pubkey = p1.pubkey
                AND p1.pubkey LIKE '%/asd/%'
        GROUP BY a1.author_name
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1);
```

But for some reason I keep getting this error "Operand should  contain 1 column(s) and I am unable to find the error.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to simply use NOT LIKE in your WHERE clause in the first SQL Statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try removing the count from the inner query. something like this maybe..

```
SELECT 
    a.author_name
FROM
    author a,publication p
WHERE
   a.pubkey = p.pubkey AND a.author_name NOT IN (SELECT 
            a1.author_name
        FROM
            publication p1,
            author a1
        WHERE
            a1.pubkey = p1.pubkey
                AND p1.pubkey LIKE '%/asd/%'
        GROUP BY a1.author_name
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1);
```